# Назначение кастомного имени для Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-shared-preferences

В своем приложении хочу реализовать сохранение данных с кастомным именем.

То есть, при нажатии кнопки Save вылезает EditText, куда пользователь вводит имя файла Shared Preferences и сохраняются необходимые текущие данные приложения (они простые - в основном номер строки в каталоге с изображениями.

Затем желательно создание новой Button, через которую эти данные можно загрузить.

Это можно как-то реализовать через Shared Preferenses или необходимо подключать SQ lite?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял тебе нужно сохранять некоторые настройки для каждого юзера (не понял зачем там юзер вводит название конечно).

С помощью SharedPreferences. SharedPreferences это хранилище ключ - значение, и тебе можно брать идентификатор (название которое ввел пользователь) за ключ, ну а значением будут твои настройки.

```
public void saveSettings(String name, int lineNumber){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(name, lineNumber);
    editor.commit();
}
```

C помощью Sqlite. Sqlite это субд и там конечно придется написать побольше кода, но это будет куда более гибкий и контролируемый вариант. Если тебе понадобиться сменить структуру хранимых настроек, как-то их все модифицировать (и прочие возможные действия со списком хранящихся данных) , то Sqlite отлично с этим справится.

Вообщем если тебе надо хранить небольшое количество данных (несколько полей) и ты знаешь что структура не изменится то можно взять SP. А если ты хочешь хранить объемное количество данных для каждого пользователя, то лучше взять Sqlite.

Comment: Выглядит отлично) Но метод getActivity() вызывает ошибку в коде. В скобках указывал и intent и this и текущее имя activity

Comment: Я скопировал кусок кода с документации Гугл) Если вы вызываете код не из Activity, то вы например можете передать Context в функцию.                 public void saveSettings(Context context, String name, int lineNumber) и вызывать на нем context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);